# D-efficient balanced design with R

Tags: r

I was wondering if there is any package for generating a D-efficient balanced design with R

I tried the [AlgDesign](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/AlgDesign/index.html) package, but I did not manage to get a balanced design.

Not sure if this is because of the small full factorial of the attributes and levels I am considering (32) or because balanced designs are out of the scope of AlgDesign.

I have 3 attributes: two attributes have four levels, and 1 has 2 levels

- att 1: 4 levels
- att 2: 4 levels
- att 3: 2 levels

I use the following R code:

```
library(AlgDesign)
#-----------------------------
# define attributes and levels
#-----------------------------
desVarNames <- c("esource", "certified", "cost")
desLevels <- c(4,2, 4)
n <- 6       #number of choice sets
desOpt <- 4  #num option per choice set

set.seed(123456)
#generate full factorial
dat<-gen.factorial(desLevels,length(desLevels),varNames=desVarNames, center=TRUE)

destT <- optFederov(~., dat, nTrials = (n*(desOpt)), criterion="D")
destT
```

Answer (score 3):

First, when you say "balanced" design, I suspect you mean that each factor level should appear the same number of times in the final design. (Actually, your variable "dat" above is a balanced design, too, since each possible combination appears only once).

The way optFederov works is by randomly selecting and replacing trials using Federov's exchange algorithm. As such, everytime a trial is exchanged with another candidate trial, an initially balanced design will become unbalanced, since if a trial "balances" a design, replacing it with any other trial will unbalance the design. If the algorithm was forced to keep a balanced design at each step, no replacement would be possible, and it would get stuck.

Not only a balanced design is incompatible with the way Feverov's exchange algorithm works, it is actually not desirable from a D-efficiency point of view.

For instance, if you have 4 factors with 2, 3, 5 and 7 levels respectively, the only way to have a balanced design is to include all 2*3*5*7 = 210 trials, whereas AlgDesign only suggests 19.

```
data = gen.factorial(c(2,3,5,7), factors = "all")
trials = optFederov(data = data, center = FALSE, criterion = "D")
```

In short, the notion of a "balanced d-efficient" design is largely antagonistic.